# Angle of radius edge?

Tags: curves

I have ordered a curved kitchen base cupboard. It is 430mm deep x 410mm wide and has a curved cupboard door. I'm having a wooden worktop cut to size from another company which has asked what angle the curve should be cut.  Please can someone tell me how I can work out the angle of the curve of the cupboard so I can get a radius edge cut in the worktop to match?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your cupboard is in the shape ABCD shown below.

[image]

AD and BC are arcs of two con-centric circles. I further assume that CD, when produced, cuts the center at O.

Select a point E as shown. Draw p and q, the perpendicular bisectors of AE and ED respectively. The point where p and q meets is the center O as required.

Measure $\alpha$ and OD.